# Image not showing up in question

Tags: bug, design, images, uploader

I have edited a number of posts on SO, recently there seems to be bug when uploading a image to question.

Consider for example if user uploads an image in their question it looks like below:

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3xf4.png)

So users like me have to add `!` before the braces of `image description`. Then the image works fine from there on. Like below:

> [image]

Comment: No bug, it's by design. Users with less than 10 reputation on SO can't upload images, as the answer in the linked post says: "The restriction has therefore simply been removed on all sites **except Stack Overflow**, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is often because [low-reputation users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) can't post images on Stack Overflow (and some other sites).

The `!` is removed so we as experienced users can check if the image is okay before everybody sees it.

Comment: What is considered "low reputation"?